# $Error variable in a Powershell Script Module/ Commandlet

Tags: powershell, error-handling, module, powershell-5.0

First, let me start off with what I want to achieve.

I am writing a PowerShell Script Module (let's call it Get-FdkUser) that's internally calling Get-AdUser and should retry a couple of times in case every but a certian Exception is thrown. Of course, because it's retrying, the error should not be logged -- it's only an error if the retries don't work.
This PowerShell Script Module is used as part of a script to go through >100,000 users. In addition to AD data, I am pulling in data from Exchange and AzureAD.

Before implementing the retries, I was recording any kind of error by checking the $Error variable. Basically like this

```
$Error.clear()
Get-ADUser
Get-Mailbox
Get-AzureADUser
if($Error.Count -gt 0) {
  Do something
}
```

Works like a charm.

Now, my issue...

**1)** In a PowerShell Script Module, the $Error variable doesnt seem to be populated. It's only populated after execution of the commandlet.
You can replicate this by checking the following code.
I find this odd even without my requirement. It seems I can never use the $Error variable in a PowerShell Script Module?

**File: ErrorTest.psm1**

```
function Get-FdkTest
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param
  ()

  try {
      $temp[-1]
  } catch {
      Write-Host "there was an error"
  }
  Write-Host "Commandlet error count $($Error.Count)"

}
Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

**Script**

```
Import-Module .\ErrorTest.psm1 -Force
$Error.Clear()
Get-FdkTest
"Error count outside of commandlet $($Error.Count)"
```

**Output**

```
there was an error
Commandlet error count 0
Error count outside of commandlet 1
```

**2)** As mentioned, Exceptions that can be fixed with retries shouldnt even surface up. Ideally I would like to remove them from the $Error variable or avoid them from being captured. Besides this not working anyway due to 1), there is maybe a better way to tackle this.

Lastly, here is the PowerShell version I am running.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.15063.1029
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.15063.1029
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Inside your `catch`, add `$global:Error.Clear()`.  Obviously, you'd only do this if it's one of the exceptions you want to ignore.

Comment: I would have to disagree. I think that wiping out ***all*** of the global error history is the wrong way to go. I think a better solution is to explicitly catch the error that you care about.

Comment: @EBGreen, yes it is a bit "nuke the site from orbit".  If you catch the specific exceptions in their own catch blocks, you can then remove them from the array like this: `$global:Error.Remove($global:Error[0])`, which will leave other exceptions untouched.

Comment: Well, the point is that if you catch the speceific ones you don't have to remove anything or rely on .Count.

Comment: Thanks very much! It's so obvious that I just didnt see it. `$global:Error.Clear()` works, makes perfect sense and helps me to implement what I want.

Comment: @EBGreen, the exceptions still end up in the global `$Error`, even if you catch them in the module, and @atlan said he didn't want them to appear if he has handled them, hence you need to remove them, or am I missing something?

Comment: @boxdog, that's exactly what I wanted. Implemented and works. And yes, I am just removing the Exceptions from $Error that I dont want to surface.

Comment: You are missing something. The more elegant way to do this is to catch specific errors that need specific actions then have a generic catch that catches everything that you don't really care about. At the end of the day if you have a way that works, use it. I'm just saying that throwing the baby out with the bath water is drastic and does not need to be done.